# Accessible HTML dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, accessibility

I need to change my dropdown menu, which works well with a mouse, but I would like to make it more accessible with keyboard.

The PHP code is:

```
<div id="nav-collapsed-icon">
    <div class="icon-menu"></div>
</div>   
<div id="menu_section"> 
    <div class="opened_menu"> 
        <nav id="nav-main" class="nav-collapse cf collapse" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-wrap">
                <div class="right_nav">
                    <?php 
                        if ( has_nav_menu( 'top_right_navigation' ) ) {
                            wp_nav_menu(array(
                                'theme_location' => 'top_right_navigation',
                                'menu_class' => 'sf-menu',
                                'link_after' => ''
                            )); 
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "more accessible"

Comment: The menu doesn't work with keyboard and I need work with him only with the keyboard

Comment: Try looking into jQuery keyboard events

Comment: The question as currently asked is very low quality.  It's very broad, and good answers would be too long / too varied.  **Why** do you want the menu more accessible? **How** do you want the menu more accessible? Are you open to using javascript / jQuery? What specifically needs to happen? "work with only keyboard" is very vague - what *specifally* do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the WAI-ARIA 1.0 Authoring Practices and look at the section on menus.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#menu

It tells you exactly how keyboard interaction should work.